# Article after AT - THE vs A/AN

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What are the rules on the use of articles after the proposition of AT?
I'm asking because I can't conclude why in the case of age, THE is used and in the case of speed or altitude, A/AN is used:

> Tracy left school at **the** age of sixteen.

and

> We are now flying at **a** speed of 800 kilometres an hour and at **an** altitude of 9000 metres.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/175729/21520

Comment: Thanks, @athlonusm. It looks like that thread contains a correct answer to a similar question.